# LaTeX: How can I disable the linking for figures in LyX?

Tags: latex, hyperlink, figure, lyx, hyperref

Complete LaTeX and LyX newbie here.

I am currently writing a document in LyX and I'm using hyperref to have links in the ToC, citations etc. The problem is that I added a figure (with float) and when I make a cross-reference in the text, the reference itself becomes a link that leads to the page that contains the actual figure. For example:

> ------Sample Graphic-------
>
> Figure 1.1: Example of a graphic

And in the text that follows:

> As we can see in figure 1.1 there is...

Now if I hover the mouse over 1.1 there is a link pointing to the location of the actual figure. Is there any way to disable the links for figures? Perhaps using "hypersetup" or something...?

Thank you in advance. :-)

Comment: Hi Andreas! Just to offer you a kind invitation: perhaps you could post your question to the TeX dedicated forum http://tex.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Thank you Stefan, I just did that. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has been solved [here on tex.stackexchange.org](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1961/how-can-i-disable-the-linking-for-figures-in-lyx). `\ref` has been redefined to work like `\ref*` that creates no link.